# SQL query to return value from sub-select that does not exist in some table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, exists

I am looking for a way to write a query that does the following:

```
SELECT NAME 
FROM   customer_table 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT NAME 
                   FROM   order_table 
                   WHERE  NAME IN ( 'Mary Smith', 'Albert Angelo', 'Bob Rogers')
                  )
```

I want the result to be a list of the names that don't exist in the CUSTOMER_TABLE that were selected from the sub-select on the ORDER_TABLE (so the values from that range that exist in the order table but don't exist in the customer_table). But this query gets me all of the other non-matching NAME values in the CUSTOMER_TABLE besides the listed in the range in the sub-query.

I want this to be able to be used for a large number of names that would be too large to enter by hand.

Comment: Your question says you want a list of names that don't exist in `customer_table` but your outer query is selecting from `customer_table` which makes the question hard to understand. Do you actually want the list of names that are in `order_table` but not in `customer_table`?

Comment: Yes, you're correct.  I want to get the names from the range specified that are in the order_table but not in the customer_table.  Sorry for the poor wording!

Comment: Then the second query in vkp's answer is correct, the one that uses left join, but I'm not going to upvote it because the first one is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is missing a correlation to the sub-query.

```
select NAME 
from order_table o
where NOT EXISTS (select 1 
                  from customer_table c
                  where o.name = c.name
                  )
```

Or you can use a `left join` to do this.

```
select o.name
from order_table o
left join customer_table c on o.name = c.name
where c.name is null
```

Comment: I'm not fully sure this is what he wants, the structure of his query suggest other wise, but maybe he was just wrong.

Comment: These two queries will have different results. That being said I think the second one is what Jennifer is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A list of the names that were selected from the first select and don't exist in the CUSTOMER_TABLE

```
SELECT NAME 
FROM   order_table 
WHERE  NAME IN ( 'Mary Smith', 'Albert Angelo', 'Bob Rogers')
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT NAME
FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want names that doesn't exists in customer_table then first retrive the names which you are looking for then write customer_table in sub query to filter those names using NOT EXISTS. But you are doing opposit by using customer_table in outer query.

Or else you can use CTE to select all names you want to compare then filter them using customer table as shown here.

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT NAME 
             FROM   order_table 
             WHERE  NAME IN ( 'Mary Smith', 'Albert Angelo', 'Bob Rogers')
)

SELECT NAME FROM CTE WHERE NAME NOT IN (SELECT NAME FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE)
```

hope this query will help you @jennifer